# invalid use of non-static member function in QT in setMouseCallback function

Tags: c++, opencv

```
    void LandslideTraining::CallBackFunc(int event,int x,int y,int  flags,void* userdata=0)   //Created a call back function 
    {
      if (event == EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN)
      {
        ab[counts][0] = x;
        ab[counts][1] = y;
        counts += 1;

        if (counts - 1 == iter)
        {
          Mat abcd(counts, 2, CV_32F, Scalar(0));
          for (int i = 0; i < counts; i++)
          {
            abcd.at<float>(i, 0) = ab[i][0];
            abcd.at<float>(i, 1) = ab[i][1];
          }
          destroyWindow(segem);
          writeMatToFile(abcd, str.toStdString().c_str());
          train(str.toStdString());
        }
     }
   }
```

/*when this function invokes the image will be display and user select the training samples from the image but when the program is building in QT getting error "invalid use of non-static member function cv::setMouseCallback(segem,CallBackFunc,this)" */

```
 void LandslideTraining::on_buttonBox_accepted() 
 {
  Mat seg1=image;
  string segem="a/b/c.jpg";
  double minVal, maxVal;
  minMaxLoc(seg1, &minVal, &maxVal);
  seg1.convertTo(seg, CV_8U, 255.0/(maxVal - minVal), -minVal * 255.0/(maxVal - minVal));
  namedWindow(segem,WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
  cv::setMouseCallback(segem,CallBackFunc,this);  
  imshow(segem,seg);
  }
```

Comment: Take a look [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14280220/how-to-use-cvsetmousecallback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14280220/how-to-use-cvsetmousecallback)