# Mouse callback event flags in Python/OpenCV/OSX?

Tags: python, opencv, callback, mouseevent, keyboard-events

I'm using OpenCV in Python on OS X (10.10.5). I'm just starting out, so I may have made a silly mistake here. However, I haven't found anything that addresses this issue.

I have a mouse callback function that makes a list containing the coordinates of each point that is clicked on in a loaded image.

Now I'd like to use the flags in the mouse callback function to control whether I append coordinates to the list or whether I instead append `('NA', 'NA')`. For example, if a point is missing from an image, I could hold the <kbd>shift</kbd> key and click on the image, and a placeholder would be appended instead of coordinates.

Although the `event` part of the mouse callback works*, the `flags` information doesn't seem to be available.

Here's the mouse callback function:

```
img_points = []

def write_points(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global img_points
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN and flags != cv2.EVENT_FLAG_SHIFTKEY:
        img_points.append((x,y))
        print img_points
    elif event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN and flags == cv2.EVENT_FLAG_SHIFTKEY:
        img_points.append(('NA','NA'))
        print img_points
```

I've tried different versions of this, and as far as I can tell the problem is that the `EVENT_FLAG_SHIFTKEY` (or any other `EVENT_FLAG_*` information) isn't available to the function.

Here's what happens if I alter the code in different ways:

- I don't include anything about flags, the coordinates of every point that is clicked on are appended to `img_points`, so the event part seems to be ok.
- If I use the function as written above, the coordinates of every point that is clicked on (regardless of whether the shift key is pressed) are appended. So `flags != cv2.EVENT_FLAG_SHIFTKEY` must always be true.
- If I use the code as written above, but replace `flags != cv2.EVENT_FLAG_SHIFTKEY` with, say, `flags == cv2.EVENT_FLAG_CTRLKEY`, then nothing happens when I click regardless of whether I'm holding any buttons. That would suggest that regardless of what I do with the keyboard, `flags == cv2.EVENT_FLAG_CTRLKEY` and `flags == cv2.EVENT_FLAG_SHIFTKEY` are both always false.

Any ideas what is wrong here? Am I using event flags incorrectly? Is it a problem with the way OS X encodes keys/right clicks? How can I fix it?

---

<sup>*</sup> Additional note: actually, the event `EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN` is the only event that works. Similar to this post, [Mouse event handling with cvSetMouseCallback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5000721/mouse-event-handling-with-cvsetmousecallback), `EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN` and the double click events don't work (a double click registers as two clicks and appends two sets of coordinates). I've tried this both with the trackpad and with an external mouse (the answer to the other post didn't solve the issue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue and a simple print statement debugging helped me out.

I recommend to print the "flags" value you are getting and compare with the value stored in cv2.EVENT_FLAG_SHIFTKEY.

In my case, I am using Windows 7 opencv 2.4.9 and cv2.EVENT_FLAG_ALTKEY is 32L but the actual flags parameter returned is 33.

Similarly, cv2.EVENT_FLAG_CTRLKEY stores 8L but I get 9 for flags param. So, probably there are some bug in cv2 interface. Likely, the Mac version too.

(edit)
2.4.12 seems to have fixed this issue already.

Comment: Thanks! This was the problem.

Comment: Good to know that it was helpful. Can you also accept the answer then?

Answer (score 4):

Actually you need to do a bitwise and (&) because the button flag and key flag are added (E.G. EVENT_FLAG_LBUTTONDOWN = 1  plus EVENT_SHIFTKEY = 16) yields a flag value of 17, so as an example to capture a double left mouse click while the Control key is pressed you need;

if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDBLCLK and (flags & cv2.EVENT_FLAG_CTRLKEY):

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I just got this to work and thought I'd share my solution:

I think the way flags register a shift click is not using just the flag by itself, but you also need to add the flag for the click. What I mean is you need to use:

`flags == (cv2.EVENT_FLAG_SHIFTKEY + cv2.EVENT_FLAG_LBUTTON)`

rather than just

`flags == cv2.EVENT_FLAG_SHIFTKEY`

This worked for me.

That said, I could also not get

`events == cv2.EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN`

to work on MAC OS X.

Hope this helps!